How to make a terminal with AsyncPro?
I want to embed a terminal in my application using AsyncPro. I installed the library but it has no demo files. Does anyone knows how can I setup a terminal ? I have a Raspberry Pi connected on the same network and a python script that execute a command and capture the output in realtime and send it to my Delphi application on my Windows laptop. So, at this stage I have a TIdBytes buffer that must be sent to the emulated terminal. And then, if the AsyncPro terminal can give me the input buffer in a TIdBytes, I can send it back to my Raspberry Pi to the running command stdin...
https://github.com/TurboPack/AsyncPro

Do you need a RS232 terminal or a TELNET terminal? Is your issue communicating with the Raspberry PI or handle escape sequences use to drive the terminal Windows (Such things as clear screen or set cursor to a give location). Do you need SSH ?

I need terminal to whom I will send myself a buffer with the data it needs to display. I already have the data in a TBytes variable. There is no need for RS232, TELNET... Of course the data is the raw stdout of the command running on the raspberry pi server, and has control characters as clear screen or set cursor to a give location...

So, the data is already available, I just don't know how to pass it to the terminal to display it...

I foun it ! It was so simple... Terminal.WriteString(TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(PBuff^));. And it seems it handle the control characters too.

For the record, AsyncPro is available on GetIt, too

@MarusGradinaru Write up the solution as an answer and then you can accept your own answer.
